# Trying to search text in an XML file for bad characters and correct them, how do I find the & symbol?

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to write a program in python that can identify bad characters in an entire XML file and correct them. I believe I have everything set up but am getting caught up on the & symbol. I believe when I load the xml file using lxml doing the following

```
        tree = ET.parse(d, parser)
        root = tree.getroot()
        iter_ = root.iter()
```

that it is converting symbols such as `&amp` to their proper xml format &

Problem is when I'm trying to use a comparison on the lines of text like such

```
                    current_line = elem.text
                    if ' & ' in current_line:
                         current_line = re.sub(' & ', ' &amp;', current_line)
                    elem.text = current_line
```

it finds all the & symbols where `&amp;` has already been converted and injects another `&amp;`, leaving it looking like `&amp;amp;`. Additionally, it seems to skip over incorrectly formatted lines where it had only & because I believe that line fails to load, which is what I'm actually looking to correct.

How can I load my text in so that the text in the tag is unformatted and can be corrected?

Comment: `ET` is already parsing the XML and converting all `&something;` sequences to the actual characters they represent. If you want to manipulate the XML before parsing it, then you have to manipulate the text itself, without using `ET` or another XML parser.

Comment: If it contains "bad characters" then it's presumably not well-formed XML, which means it will be rejected by an XML parser. You need to use non-XML tools to process it. Note: standards give you no value unless you actually conform to them. The best way to deal with bad XML is the same way you deal with other shoddy goods - send it back and demand a refund.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, so glad that it's confirming my suspicions. I was hoping to use the parser to isolate the text content between tags for that purpose, but doesn't look like it's doable. I might ab least get it to work as a integrity verifier. Thank you.